How to delete my Git Credentials from Keychain on MacOs?
I am facing an issue with Visual Studio for Mac related to handling Git credentials. Every time I delete my Git credentials from the macOS Keychain using the terminal, they get automatically re-added when I run a Git command from within Visual Studio.
Steps I've Taken:

I used the command git credential-osxkeychain erase followed by inputting:
host=github.com
protocol=https

This effectively removes the credentials from the macOS Keychain.

However, when I execute any Git command from Visual Studio for Mac, such as git pull, it seems to automatically restore the previously deleted credentials to the Keychain without prompting me.


How can I prevent Visual Studio for Mac from automatically restoring deleted Git credentials?
I've tried looking through Visual Studio preferences related to Version Control and Git, but haven't found anything that directly addresses this issue. I'm trying to log in with a new GitHub account and need Visual Studio to prompt me for the new credentials instead of restoring the old ones.
Any advice is greatly appreciated!

If you're worried about your password being stored, it may be simpler to just change your password.

@Evert I need to use another github account on my mac, but I couldn't delete my old credentials to login with my new github account
